# Display AjaxControlToolkit.Twitter dynamically?

Tags: vb.net, twitter, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to show dynamically AjaxControlToolkit.Twitter by creating new instance and binding new screen name to the Twitter and place this control to Panel. But it's not working. Any suggestions?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim RandomNumber As New Random()
        Dim rn As Short
        rn = RandomNumber.Next(1, 6)
        Select Case rn
            Case rn = 1
                Dim tw As New AjaxControlToolkit.Twitter()
                tw.ScreenName = "aspnet"
                tw.DataBind()
                pnlTw.Controls.Add(tw)
            Case rn = 2
                Dim tw As New AjaxControlToolkit.Twitter
                tw.ScreenName = "smashingmag"
                tw.DataBind()
                pnlTw.Controls.Add(tw)
            Case rn = 3
                Dim tw As New AjaxControlToolkit.Twitter
                tw.ScreenName = "LessThanDot"
                tw.DataBind()
                pnlTw.Controls.Add(tw)
            Case rn = 4
                Dim tw As New AjaxControlToolkit.Twitter
                tw.ScreenName = "scottgu"
                tw.DataBind()
                pnlTw.Controls.Add(tw)
            Case rn = 5
                Dim tw As New AjaxControlToolkit.Twitter
                tw.ScreenName = "Encosia"
                tw.DataBind()
                pnlTw.Controls.Add(tw)
            Case rn = 6
                Dim tw As New AjaxControlToolkit.Twitter
                tw.ScreenName = "domvtae"
                tw.DataBind()
                pnlTw.Controls.Add(tw)
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved - just changed case to if condition. ))